# add marker based on coordinates google maps

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I really need some help on this, it's quite hard for me to figure out how would the best way to do this.

Controller:

```
def merchant_ids
    merchants = Merchant.where(id: params[:id]).pluck(:merchant_name, :id, :merchant_city, :physical_address, :merchant_phone, :latitude, :longitude)
    render json: merchants
  end
```

this is for showing the user the information based on the selected `merchant`.

example:

```
[["Burger King",1,"Aguadilla","Burger King Plaza Real","78778778787",18.3703084883462,-66.0766804218292]]
```

Javascript:

```
// this one display the information based on the selected value
$('#complaint_merchant_id').chosen().change(function(){
    var clean_html = $('#merchant_name, #physical_address, #merchant_phone');
    var clean_value = $('#merchants_latitude, #merchants_longitude');
    clean_html.html('');
    clean_value.val('');
    $.ajax('/dashboard/merchants/merchant_ids/' + this.value).done(function(data){
        for (var city in data);
        $('#merchant_name').append(data[city][0]);
        $('#physical_address').append(data[city][3]);
        $('#merchant_phone').append(data[city][4]);
        $('#merchants_latitude').val(data[city][5]);
        $('#merchants_longitude').val(data[city][6]);
    }) ;
});
```

I have the gmaps.js storing the latitude and longitude in a `float` in the database in the merchants record

schema:

```
  create_table "merchants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "merchant_name"
    t.string   "merchant_city"
    t.string   "postal_address"
    t.string   "physical_address"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "merchant_phone"
    t.string   "merchant_secondary_phone"
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
  end
```

in the view I have two fields to put the latitude and longitude that gets pulled from the database depending on which merchant is selected:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
      <%= label '', 'Nombre de Proveedor/Agencia:' %><br>
      <span class="color-main" id="merchant_name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= label '', 'Dirección local:' %><br>
      <span class="color-main" id="physical_address"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <%= label '', 'Teléfono:' %><br>
       <span class="color-main" id="merchant_phone"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" id="merchants_latitude"/>
        <input type="text" id="merchants_longitude"/>
      </div>
```

What I need to do is when they select a merchant, it will put a marker based on the latitude and longitude of the current selected merchant and center the map to the marker.

I only know how to do the eventListener for clicking in the map but to refresh the marker when someone selects an option in a  tag outside of the map I currently don't know how to.

I have the map loading in a

```
<div id="map-complaints" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
```

Thank you for your time, really appreciate.

edit:

this is how I select the merchant:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <%= f.label :merchant_id, 'Seleccione proveedor o agencia de servicios' %>
  <% merchants_array = @merchants.map { |merchant| [merchant.merchant_name, merchant.id] } %>
  <%= f.select :merchant_id, merchants_array, {include_blank: true}, {class: 'chosen-select form-control', tabindex: '-1'} %>
 </div>
```

Comment: How do you select the merchant ?

Comment: @scaisEdge I've edited the question, basically I pull an array from the database into the select input, also, I'm currently using `chosen.js` for this if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution was to use such an onclick event on the  by which selection is made of the merchant. This onClick must contain a call to a javascript function that creates the marker. Since the div have the coordinates where to place the marker, the function call javascript may contain the information necessary for proper placement on the map.

Comment: This is the idea, but I don't really know how to get google maps to read the coords from the 2 fields and then place the marker based on them.